# errors when i open terminal

Tags: google-app-engine, terminal, gcloud

I was trying to install google app engine sdk on my mac but i put the sdk folder on the desktop and wanted to move it. I found advice saying to just delete it and reinstall but now every time i open a new terminal it says

> /Users/myusername/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc: No such file
>   or directory

even though i reinstalled in a different location (i have since deleted that folder as well). How can I stop gettting this error every time I open a terminal and how can I get terminal to look in the new location (gcloud also does not work obviously when the folder is not on the desktop)? I also get

> -bash: /Users/myusername/.bash_profile: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

and

> -bash: /Users/myusername/.bash_profile: line 7: `fi'

every time I open a new terminal even when the google-cloud-sdk folder is on my desktop and the first error isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Upon installation, the google cloud sdk adds itself to your `PATH`. Probably in your `~/.bash_profile`.

You will need to edit that file and remove the wrong entry and point the installation to the right location if it's not already present.

Eg with gcloud installed in the home directory(`~/`):

```
# This updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f ~/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc ]; then
  source '~/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi
```

You'll then need to restart your terminal or `source ~/.bash_profile` for the changes to take effect.